# How to use VirtualBox on raw disk where I have my system

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox

I have a dualboot on the same physical drive, but not on the same partition. In windows, I'd like to use virtualbox to boot on linux, like that:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "..." -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive0
```

But it can't be offline since I have the system here. Maybe there is a way to virtualize a raw drive